# AWS DMS (Data Migration Service) Table Full Load Timeout after 5 minutes

Tags: amazon-web-services, database-migration, amazon-aurora

I'm trying to use DMS to migrate a MySQL database from EC2 (200gb) to a new RDS Aurora instance. The problem is that not all rows are migrated.

Every table only get 5 minutes to fully load the table, and if it's not finished after these 5 minutes, DMS stops loading this table and goes into "Table completed" state.

I find this in the UNLOAD SOURCE DETAILED_DEBUG logfile:

Entering mysql_unload_init_table, **unloadtimeout: 300** (mysql_endpoint_unload.c:131)

Does anybody know how to increase this? I think there was once the possibility to call aws dms modify-endpoint api and pass MySQLSettings but this is not available anymore. How can this be achieved now?

I have a table with 200.000.000 records to migrate and this takes obviously more than 5 minutes.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

I get the answer on a different channel. This might help someone else in the future!

> We were encountering the same issue doing a MySQL RDS -> MySQL Aurora
>   migration with DMS. Any table that took longer than 5 minutes would
>   stop migrating, claim to be complete, then fail validation. Adding the
>   following source connection attributes fixed the issue for us (set
>   UnloadTimeout to a relevant value for you, I'm using 1 day as a test):
>
> **ResumeFetchForXRows=0;UnloadTimeout=86400**
>
> Additionally, AWS support sent me the following:
>
> "There is a known issue when doing full load on MySQL Source,MySQL
>   server will return there isn't more data when fetching the next
>   records even if there are more records still in the table. To resolve
>   the issue, I recommend you to add "Resumefetchforxrows=0" into extra
>   **connection attribute of the source endpoint**. This should fix your
>   issue. To do this edit your source endpoint in the DMS console and add
>   the attribute."
>
> I found that the **UnloadTimeout parameter had the greatest impact for us**.

Comment: Is this still the only solution? What concerns me is that both these settings (`ResumeFetchForXRows` and `UnloadTimeout`) are not in AWS documentation, so I'm not sure about their stability.